# how to plot non linear data in dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a json data file with a structure that is kind of complicated, something like that:

```
[
  {
    "patient_id": "f1ff9870",
    "demographics": {
      "gender": "female",
      "age": 78
    },
    "measurements": [
      {
        "unit": "bpm",
        "kind": "pulse",
        "value": "130",
        "measurementDate": "2017-05-04 03:00:00+03"
      }
    ],
    "problems": [
      {
        "name_title": "problem1",
        "category": "Primary disease",
        "startDate": "2017-05-12 03:00:00+03"
      },
      {
        "name_title": "problem2",
        "category": "Primary disease",
        "startDate": "2017-05-12 03:00:00+03"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "patient_id": "c9047712",
    "demographics": {
      "gender": "male",
      "age": 60
    }
  }
]
```

each object is a patient who can have several fields, some of them are arrays, and not all the patients have the same number of fields.

I am trying to find a way to use the crossfilter and make the groups for the plots but I am not really close to a solution. I want to use charts, for each field(i.e. problems, age etc), and each one should be a filter. So, if i select a specific problem i will be able to see how many patients have that problem, their age, measurements etc. Is there a way to work around non linear data?

Comment: As long as you want to filter and aggregate at the patient level, this sort of data should work. You would need to transform your data if you wanted to filter and aggregate on something inside the records, like "problems". Could you edit your question and describe what you are trying to plot?

Comment: i just edited the question. The idea is to plot each attribute and each plot to be used as a filter that can modify the rest. If it is possible of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question. Let me address this specific part of it:

> if i select a specific problem i will be able to see how many patients have that problem, their age, measurements etc.

"Problems" can be thought of as a [tag or array dimension](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays).

So you could aggregate problems and age like this:

```
var cf = crossfilter(data);
var problemsDim = cf.dimension(d => d.problems.map(p => p.category), true);
var ageDim = cf.dimension(d => d.demographics.age);
var problemsGroup = problemsDim.group(); // default is "reduceCount"
var ageGroup = ageDim.group();
```

Now when you select a specific problem you'll see counts of all patients who have that problem. When you select a specific age, you'll get a count of all patients who have each problem.

Note that with tag dimensions, the total of all the counts will usually add up to more than the number of records.

You could do something similar for measurements. Of course some patients may not have problems or measurements, so they wouldn't show up in those charts. Also you might end up with weird results if a patient had more than one of the same measurement.